# How to remove the scrollbar from my website ? Work arounds didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using react framework for designing a website. The website is well designed and complete . Now I see that my website is scrolling through y axis . I have seen work around like overflow:hidden but the screen design will be impacted because it has margin on top and bottom. Can anyone look into it and tell me answer?

GitHub link:
https://github.com/sandeyshc/ACME-frontend

Website link:
https://6127a673da25ff00079834e6--pedantic-goldberg-0f0184.netlify.app/

App.js

```
  return(
<div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-1 grid-cols-2 gap-0 helloss col-span-2" style={{backgroundColor:'black',padding:'4% 8%', resize:"contain"}}>
  <div className={sizes} style={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
  <Login />
  {/* style={{resizeMode: 'contain'}} */}
  </div>
  <div className="hellosm">
  <img src={logoss}/>
  </div>
</div>
  );
```

App.css

```
img{
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .hellosm{
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;

  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to help you. But I don't see any scroll bar in the above netlify webpage

Comment: I see no scroll bar... perhaps include an image of what you are seeing and the screen size you are seeing it on

Comment: @GeorgeRaveen, DevWithZachary There is scroll bar on right but since the background is black you are unable to see it. Here is the link https://ibb.co/CnBmy0k

Comment: It seems like your screen height is small. then you have to reduce the size of your elements or reduce top margin

Comment: @GeorgeRaveen I tried changing the height of many elements but it didn't work. Can u suggest me where to change the height from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use webkit-scrollbar

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
html{
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: I tried overflow :hidden but there is padding on top and bottom so the overflow :hidden gives irregular padding on top and bottom

Comment: did you try x and y?

Comment: Yeah but it will just hide content outside of body, it won't fix that issue.

Comment: I just updated my code, check it out, it will work now